# Cannot Open database requested By Login , For Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlconnection

I Have Created a Windows Form Application with Visual Studio 2010 and SQL EXPRESS R2 2008, When i Run it in Visual Studio ID, it runs Flawlessly , But Once I Made The exe file and Install it in My PC  It gives the Error "CAnnot Open DataBase "Biling" requested by the  login , 
Here is The App Config File

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="webAppCon" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESSR2;Initial Catalog=Billing;User ID=sa;Password=pswrd" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="Billing.Properties.Settings.BillingConnectionString1" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESSR2;Initial Catalog=Billing;User ID=sa;Password=pswrd" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

This is The Error

[`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSAH6.png)

Comment: Your PC is the same machine where you have developed the application?

Comment: yes i tested the application in my pc where i developed the app

Comment: The error says "login failed for user sa". Double check the password in your connection string, maybe it has been dropped by the deploy procedure for security reasons

Comment: @mCasamento, i have cheked the password  in  the <app>.exe xml file it is the same as i provided in the app.config file

Comment: Thank you steave and mCasamento for the replay , i found the solution, some how my database 'billing' went offline that was the probelm . once i brought it oline , it worked perfectly